# Inverse of the sum of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have two square matrices: $A$ and $B$. $A^{-1}$ is known and I want to calculate $(A+B)^{-1}$. Are there theorems that help with calculating the inverse of the sum of matrices? In general case $B^{-1}$ is not known, but if it is necessary then it can be assumed that $B^{-1}$ is also known.

Comment: This [article](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2690437) may be of help, although I don't have access to it right now.

Comment: @Arturo: I know that they might not be invertible, but let's assume they are.
@Adrian: Unfortunately I don't have direct access to jstor.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2977195/2987

Answer (score 195, accepted):

In general, $A+B$ need not be invertible, even when $A$ and $B$ are. But one might ask whether you can have a formula under the additional assumption that $A+B$ *is* invertible.

As noted by Adrián Barquero, there is [a paper by Ken Miller](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2690437) published in the *Mathematics Magazine* in 1981 that addresses this.

He proves the following:

**Lemma.** If $A$ and $A+B$ are invertible, and $B$ has rank $1$, then let $g=\operatorname{trace}(BA^{-1})$. Then $g\neq -1$ and
$$(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{1}{1+g}A^{-1}BA^{-1}.$$

From this lemma, we can take a general $A+B$ that is invertible and write it as $A+B = A + B_1+B_2+\cdots+B_r$, where $B_i$ each have rank $1$ and such that each $A+B_1+\cdots+B_k$ is invertible (such a decomposition always exists if $A+B$ is invertible and $\mathrm{rank}(B)=r$). Then you get:

**Theorem.** Let $A$ and $A+B$ be nonsingular matrices, and let $B$ have rank $r\gt 0$. Let $B=B_1+\cdots+B_r$, where each $B_i$ has rank $1$, and each $C_{k+1} = A+B_1+\cdots+B_k$ is nonsingular. Setting $C_1 = A$, then
$$C_{k+1}^{-1} = C_{k}^{-1} - g_kC_k^{-1}B_kC_k^{-1}$$
where $g_k = \frac{1}{1 + \operatorname{trace}(C_k^{-1}B_k)}$. In particular,
$$(A+B)^{-1} = C_r^{-1} - g_rC_r^{-1}B_rC_r^{-1}.$$

(If the rank of $B$ is $0$, then $B=0$, so $(A+B)^{-1}=A^{-1}$).

Comment: The lemma is the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), isn't it?

Comment: Can this theorem be used in finding the inverse of $${\large[}g_{\mu\nu}+\chi \frac{k_\mu k_\nu}{k^2}{\large]}$$ where $g$ is the Minkowski metric tensor and the $k$'s are four-vectors? Please see this question in Physics.SE: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/141613/31965 Thanks.

Comment: What about the case of $ \left( A + \lambda I \right)^{-1} $? Let's assume $ A $ is PSD.

Comment: I am also interested in the case $(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{I})^{-1}$. Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2680914/inverse-of-symmetric-matrix-plus-identity-matrix?noredirect=1#comment5539327_2680914

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2977195/2987

Comment: It may be useful to note that the rank of the outer product, $\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v^T}$, of nonzero vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$, is 1. So the lemma can be used in cases where $B=\mathbf{u}\mathbf{v^T}$, which may come up in linear regression settings when $B = \mathbf{x_i}\mathbf{x_i^T}$

Comment: That's a nice lemma. Used it to solve "inverse of a variance in random effects ANOVA" in 3 lines!

Comment: @bob, every rank one matrix has that form (i.e. is outer product of two vectors).

Answer (score 73):

It is shown in [On Deriving the Inverse of a Sum of Matrices](http://dspace.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/32750/1/BU-647-M.version2.pdf) that

$(A+B)^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}B(A+B)^{-1}$.

This equation cannot be used to calculate $(A+B)^{-1}$, but it is useful for perturbation analysis where $B$ is a perturbation of $A$. There are several other variations of the above form (see equations (22)-(26) in this paper).

This result is good because it only requires $A$ and $A+B$ to be nonsingular. As a comparison, the SMW identity or Ken Miller's paper (as mentioned in the other answers) requires some nonsingualrity  or rank conditions of $B$.

Comment: What about the case of $ \left( A + \lambda I \right)^{-1} $? Let's assume $ A $ is PSD.

Comment: This follows directly from Woodbury Matrix Identity.  Let C=I, V=I.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2977195/2987

Answer (score 47):

$(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}BA^{-1} + A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1} - A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1} + \cdots$

provided $\|A^{-1}B\|<1$ or $\|BA^{-1}\| < 1$ (here $\|\cdot\|$ means norm).  This is just the Taylor expansion of the inversion function together with basic information on convergence.

(posted essentially at the same time as mjqxxx)

Answer (score 46):

This I found accidentally.

Suppose given $A$, and $B$, where $A$ and $A+B$ are invertible. Now we want to know the expression of $(A+B)^{-1}$ without imposing the all inverse. Now we follow the intuition like this. Suppose that we can express $(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} + X$, next we will present simple straight forward method to compute $X$
\begin{equation}
(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} + X
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(A^{-1} + X) (A + B) = I 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
A^{-1} A + X A + A^{-1} B + X B = I 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X(A + B)  = - A^{-1} B
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X  = - A^{-1} B ( A + B)^{-1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X  = - A^{-1} B (A^{-1} + X)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
(I + A^{-1}B) X  = - A^{-1} B A^{-1} 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X  = - (I + A^{-1}B)^{-1} A^{-1} B A^{-1}
\end{equation}

This lemma is simplification of lemma presented by Ken Miller, 1981

Comment: Where did you find this? Can you give a citation?

Comment: How is this a simplification of the lemma shown in Ken Miller 1981? Are we talking about "On the Inverse of the Sum of Matrices" or any other work? (In any case, I find this property quite useful, just need to cite it properly).

Comment: Interesting to notice that line 3 is a Sylvester equation.

Comment: In order to conclude last line,we must have (I+A^-1B) invertible. So how are we sure about that, It might be easy but (I am not getting. Can you please explain @ Muhammad Fuday.

Comment: @Sry: I'm not certain how this formula helps.  For example, the deduction $(I+A^{-1}B)^{-1} = (A+B)^{-1} A$ is direct, so the above formula is basically just the statement $(A+B)^{-1})(A+B)=I$.   Among other things $I+A^{-1}B$ is invertible if and only if $A+B$ is invertible.  i.e. you have to check invertibility of two equivalent matrices.

Answer (score 42):

I'm surprising that no one realize it's a special case of the well-known `matrix inverse lemma` or `[Woodbury matrix identity]`, it says,

$ \left(A+UCV \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1}U \left(C^{-1}+VA^{-1}U \right)^{-1} VA^{-1}$ ,

just set U=V=I, it immediately gets

$ \left(A+C \right)^{-1} = A^{-1} - A^{-1} \left(C^{-1}+A^{-1} \right)^{-1} A^{-1}$ .

Answer (score 29):

A formal power series expansion is possible:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(A + \epsilon B)^{-1}
&=& \left(A \left(I + \epsilon A^{-1}B\right)\right)^{-1} \\
&=& \left(I + \epsilon A^{-1}B\right)^{-1} A^{-1} \\
&=& \left(I - \epsilon A^{-1}B + \epsilon^2 A^{-1}BA^{-1}B - ...\right) A^{-1} \\
&=& A^{-1} - \epsilon A^{-1} B A^{-1} + \epsilon^2 A^{-1} B A^{-1} B A^{-1} - ...
\end{eqnarray}
$$
Under appropriate conditions on the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ (such that $A$ is sufficiently "large" compared to $B$), this will converge to the correct result at $\epsilon=1$.

Comment: The point about eigenvalues is apt, because this works even if $\|A^{-1}B\|\geq1$ and $\|BA{^-1}\|\geq1$ as long as the spectral radius of $A^{-1}B$ or $BA^{-1}$ is less than $1$.

Comment: What about the case of $ \left( A + \lambda I \right)^{-1} $? Let's assume $ A $ is PSD.

Comment: Royi check Neumann series https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series

Answer (score 15):

Assuming everything is nicely invertible, you are probably looking for [the SMW identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity)  (which, i think, can also be generalized to pseudoinverses if needed)

Please see caveat in the comments below; in general if $B$ is low-rank, then you'd be happy using SMW.

Comment: It also requires $(A^{-1} + B^{-1})^{-1}$ to be known, doesn't it?

Comment: The Sherman-Morrison "update" formula is most efficient if $B$ is of low rank.  So the usual application (rank one or two if symmetry is to be preserved) doesn't require $B^{-1}$ to exist.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: yes, actually smw does require that inverse, which actually renders this answer useless, unless one is looking for inverses where $B$ is low-rank, and is written as $B=UCV^T$.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to come up with pretty simple examples where $A$,$A^{-1}$,$B$, and $B^{-1}$ are all very nice, but applying $(A+B)^{-1}$ is considered very difficult.

The canonical example is where $A = \Delta$ is a finite difference implementation of the [Laplacian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) on a regular grid (with, for example, Dirichlet boundary conditions), and $B=k^2I$ is a multiple of the identity. The finite difference laplacian and it's inverse are very nice and easy to deal with, as is the identity matrix. However, the combination 
$$\Delta + k^2 I$$
is the [Helmholtz operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation), which is widely known as being extremely difficult to solve for large $k$.

Answer (score 6):

If A and B were numbers, there is no simpler way to write $\frac{1}{A+B}$ in term of $ \frac{1}{A}$ and $B$ so I don't know why you would expect there to be for matrices. It is even possible to have matrices, A and B, so that neither $A^{-1}$ **nor** $B^{-1}$ exist but $(A+B)^{-1}$ does or, conversely, such that both $A^{-1}$ **and** $B^{-1}$ exist but $(A+B)^{-1}$ doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

I know the question has been answered multiple times with great answers, but with my answer you don't need to memorize any lemmas or formulas.

Suppose $(A+B)x=y$, then $x=(A+B)^{-1}y$. This is all we need to get. The steps are:

(1) Start with $(A+B)x=y$.

(2) Then $Ax=y-Bx$, so $x=A^{-1}y -A^{-1}Bx$.

(3) Multiply $x$ in step (2) by $B$ to get 
 $$Bx=BA^{-1}y -BA^{-1}Bx$$
 which is equivalent to
 $$(I+BA^{-1})Bx=BA^{-1}y $$
 or,
 $$Bx=(I+BA^{-1})^{-1}BA^{-1}y $$

(3) Substitute this $Bx$ into the $x$ in step (2) to get
 $$x=A^{-1}y -A^{-1}(I+BA^{-1})^{-1}BA^{-1}y $$

(4) Now factorizing the $y$ gives you the required result.
 $$x=(A^{-1} -A^{-1}(I+BA^{-1})^{-1}BA^{-1})y $$

(5)The assumptions we have used are $A$ and $I+BA^{-1}$ are nonsingular.

(6) We can factorize the $A^{-1}$ to get:
$$(A+B)^{-1}=A^{-1}(I -(I+BA^{-1})^{-1}BA^{-1})$$

Answer (score 4):

Extending Muhammad Fuady's approach:
We have:
\begin{equation}
(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} + X
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X  = - (I + A^{-1}B)^{-1} A^{-1} B A^{-1}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - (I + A^{-1}B)^{-1} A^{-1} B A^{-1} \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{equation}
This rearranges to:
\begin{equation}
(A+B)^{-1} = (I - (I + A^{-1}B)^{-1} A^{-1} B )A^{-1} \tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{equation}
If we consider the part
\begin{equation}
(I + A^{-1}B)^{-1}
\end{equation}
Then, this is an inverse of a sum of two matrices, so we can use \eqref{eq2}, setting $A=I$ and $B = A^{-1}B$, this gives:
\begin{equation}
(I + A^{-1}B)^{-1} = (I - (I + A^{-1}B)^{-1}A^{-1}B )
\end{equation}
so we can substitute the LHS of this for the right hand side which appears in \eqref{eq2},  giving:
\begin{equation}
(A+B)^{-1} = (I + A^{-1}B)^{-1}A^{-1} \tag{3}\label{eq3}
\end{equation}
Which is simpler than \eqref{eq1} and is very similar to the scalar identity:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{a+b}=\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{b}{a}\right)a} \tag{4}\label{eq4}
\end{equation}

The technique is useful in computation, because if the values in A and B can be very different in size then calculating  $\frac{1}{A+B}$ according to \eqref{eq3} gives a more accurate floating point result than if the two matrices are summed.

Answer (score 3):

Actually we can directly from @Shiyu answer about perturbations by subtracting $(A+B)^{-1}$ and factoring arrive at

$$0=A^{-1}-(A^{-1}B+I)(A+B)^{-1}$$ followed by$$(A+B)^{-1}=(A^{-1}B+I)^{-1}A^{-1}$$

And by symmetry of course

$$(A+B)^{-1}=(B^{-1}A+I)^{-1}B^{-1}$$

Now remember, $(I+X)^{-1}$ can be expanded as $I-X+X^2+\cdots$ by geometric series.

So if $X=B^{-1}A$ or $X=A^{-1}B$ and multiplication by $A,B$ and either of $A^{-1}$ or $B^{-1}$ are cheap, then this could work nicer than some other method of finding inverse.

Answer (score -2):

By means of augmented matrix,

A+B|I

Left times A⁻¹:

I+A⁻¹B|A^-1

abstract the common factor B:

(B^-1+A^-1)B|A^-1

left times (B^-1+A^-1)^-1:

B|(B^-1+A^-1)⁻¹A^-1

left times B^-1:

I|B^-1(B^-1+A^-1)⁻¹A^-1

thus (A+B)⁻¹=B⁻¹(B⁻¹+A⁻¹)⁻¹A⁻¹

Comment: We have a Latex-like typesetting system for mathematical expressions, called MathJax. Information is here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10164