# Does any equation holds for inverse(A- B)?

Tags: matrices, inverse

is it possible to calculate inverse of A-B, i have calculated inverse of A and B already.

A and B are matrices

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inverse of the sum of matrices](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express $(A-B)^{-1} = -(B-A)^{-1}$ in terms of either matrix and the inverse of the other matrix as a formal power series; however, the convergence of these series are not guaranteed.
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
(A-B)^{-1} &=& \left(A(I-A^{-1}B)\right)^{-1} \\ &=& \left(I-A^{-1}B\right)^{-1}A^{-1} \\ &=& +A^{-1} + A^{-1}BA^{-1} + A^{-1}BA^{-1}BA^{-1} + ... \\ &=& -B^{-1} - B^{-1}AB^{-1} - B^{-1}AB^{-1}AB^{-1} - ...
\end{eqnarray}
$$