# power of square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two square matrices $X$ and $Y$.
Given :$X = I - XY$ and $Y^3 = 0$
how can I show that $X = I - Y + Y^2$ 
I tried raising to the power of $3$ both sides of the first equation but it didn't help much.

Comment: Write $X(I+Y)=I$, and $I=I-Y^3=\cdots$.

Comment: Yes, X is invertible and X's inverse is (I + Y) but even if I raise this equation to the power of three it gets me nowhere

Comment: so I wrote X(I + Y) = I - Y^3 but then I get to X = I - XY - Y^3

Comment: still not able to prove it, any other clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $(I+Y)(I-Y+Y^2)=I+Y^3=I$, so $(I+Y)^{-1}=I-Y+Y^2$. Now $X(I+Y)=I$, so $X=(I+Y)^{-1}$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand we basically show that (I - Y + Y^2) is the inverse of (I + Y) and since X is also the inverse of (I + Y) and there is only one inverse we get that X = I - Y + Y^2

Comment: For the general formula for the inverse of $I+Y$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298616/what-is-inverse-of-ia), or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140348/prove-that-ai-is-invertible-if-a-is-nilpotent).

Answer (score 1):

$X=1-XY$ gives $XY^2=Y^2-XY^3=Y^2$

Also $X=1-XY$ gives $XY=Y-XY^2=Y-Y^2$

So $X=1-XY= 1-Y+Y^2$