# Is there close form for the eigendecomposition of a the kronecker product of a matrix with itself $A \otimes A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a matrix $A$ can we write the eigendecomposition of $A \otimes A$ if we know the eigendecomposition of $A$.

I am trying to use this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1793081/762889) to solve
$$((A \otimes A) + I)^{-1}$$ in an efficient manner.

Comment: If $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n$ are eigenvalues of $A$, and $e_1,\dots,e_n$ is an eigenbasis, then any $\lambda_{ij} = \lambda_i \lambda_j$ is an eigenvalue of $A \otimes A$ with an eigenvector $e_i \otimes e_j$. The set of such vectors for all $1 \leq i, j \leq n$ form an eigenbasis of $A \otimes A$.

Comment: When you say $e_1 \otimes e_j$, what does this notation mean? As this should be a vector?

Comment: I think you should define what you mean by tensor product $\otimes$ because you comment does not really make sense if $A \otimes A$ is defined the canonical way...

Comment: Yep sorry stupid comment from me $e_1 \otimes e_j$ makes sense, this is a vector.

Comment: @OleksandrKulkov I was wondering where you got this from, do you have a reference. Thanks.

Comment: E.g. [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Abstract_properties). I mean, it's just $(A \otimes A) (e_i \otimes e_j) = (A e_i) \otimes (A e_j) = (\lambda_i e_i) \otimes (\lambda_j e_j) = \lambda_i \lambda_j (e_i \otimes e_j)$.

Comment: I wonder if we know $E^{-1}$ in the eigendecomposition $A = EDE^{-1}$ then is there a good way of using this to compute $P^{-1}$, where $A \otimes A = P \Lambda P^{-1}$ using what you have said?