# Inverting a special matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Consider matrices $A$ and $B$ of the forms below:

$$A = \lambda \cdot I$$
$$B = \beta \cdot
\pmatrix{
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
1 & 1 & \cdots & 1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots&\vdots\\
1 & 1 & \cdots &1
}$$

In other words, $A$ is a diagonal matrix with all elements of the main diagonal equal and $B$ is a matrix of the same size as $A$ but with all of its elements equal to $\beta$.

Now, consider the matrix $C = A + B$. Is there any formula for $C^{-1}$ based on $A$, $A^{-1}$, $B$?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no $B^{-1}$ since $B$ is degenerate.

Comment: You can also assume $A=I$. Then if the inverse to $C$ exists, then you should have $C^{-1}=I-B+B^2-B^3+\dots$

Comment: Whoa, boy!  Watch out!  $B^{-1}$ can't exist, since all the rows and columns of $B$ are equal, $\det(B) = 0$!

Comment: Yep! my bad, B^{-1} doesn't exist !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2690437?uid=3737416&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21102179052193) answers to your question. See also [this topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices)

Answer (score 1):

I tried some examples with WolframAlpha:

It looks like:

$$A + B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \Rightarrow (A+B)^{-1} = \frac{1}{n\lambda\beta+\beta^2}\left(A-B+n\beta I\right)$$

Comment: what is $\lambda$ ?

Comment: @Sam: Read the question.

Comment: Sam wrote the OP himself. $\lambda$ are the entries in $A$ ($A = \lambda I$).

Comment: @dfeuer: funny!!! I am the one who posted the question ! :))))
For some reasons I read $\beta$ as B then I thought it's for general A and B ! You are right !