# Proof of matrix inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Prove that 
$(A+uv^T)^{-1}=A^{-1}-\frac{1}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}$

Can someone give a hint how to show it.I am not getting from where to start.

Comment: Show that the product is the identity matrix.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $\;A+uv^T\color{red}I\;$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio: I assume $u,v$ are meant as one column, i.e. $uv^T$ is a $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: yes u and v are $n\times 1$ vectors

Comment: The most voted answer in here might help you.

Cheers!

http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}
&(A+uv^T)
\left(A^{-1}-\frac{1}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}\right)=\\
&=I-\frac{1}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}uv^TA^{-1}+
uv^TA^{-1}-\frac{1}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}uv^TA^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}\\
&=I+\frac{v^TAu}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}uv^TA^{-1}-\frac{v^TA^{-1}u}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}uv^TA^{-1}=I,
\end{align}
since 
$$
uv^TA^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}=(v^TA^{-1}u)uv^TA^{-1},
$$
as $v^TA^{-1}u$ is scalar.
Thus 
$$
(A+uv^T)^{-1}=A^{-1}-\frac{1}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}.
$$

Comment: PAssing from the second to the third line isn't very clear ( to me), but anyway I think the third line's second term's numerator should have $\;A^{-1}\;$ and not $\;A\;$ ...

Answer (score 2):

HINT. Just calculate the product of the RHS and $A+uv^T$, and use that $v^TA^{-1}u$ is a scalar and hence commutes with everything.