# Representation of the inverse of an variance-covariance matrix $\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, covariance

Given $T$ observed vectors $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^N, i\in\{1,\ldots,T\}$. Define $\hat{\Sigma}$ as the corresponding empirical covariance-matrix of the Observations $X=\left(\begin{array}{c}
 x_1'  \\ 
  \vdots\\
x_T'
\end{array}\right)
\in\mathbb{R}^{T \times N}$.

\begin{align}
\hat{\Sigma}:=\frac{1}{T-1}X'(I_T-\frac{1}{T}\iota_T\iota_T')X
\end{align}
I am searching for an intuitive representation of $ \hat{\Sigma}^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [**this answer,**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices/17780#17780) if the inverse of $X'X$ exists, one idea is to rewrite
$$\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}=(T-1)\left(X'X-\underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}X'\iota_T}_{:=B}\underbrace{\iota_T'X\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}}_{B'}\right)^{-1}\\=(T-1)\left((X'X)^{-1}-\frac{1}{1+B'(X'X)^{-1}B}(X'X)^{-1}BB'(X'X)^{-1}\right)\\
=(T-1)\left((X'X)^{-1}-\underbrace{\frac{1}{T+\iota_T'X(X'X)^{-1}X'\iota_T}}_{:=c}(X'X)^{-1}X'\iota_T\iota_T'X(X'X)^{-1}\right)\\
=(T-1)(X'X)^{-1}\left((X'X)-\frac{1}{c}X'\iota_T\iota_T'X\right)(X'X)^{-1}
$$
If we assume the number of observations $T$ is high, the scalar $c:=T+\iota_T'X(X'X)^{-1}X'\iota_T\approx T.$  Especially as $\iota_T'X(X'X)^{-1}X'\iota_T>0$ we know $\frac{1}{c}<\frac{1}{T}$.
Given we are satisfied with this approximation we can write
$$
\hat{\Sigma}^{-1}\approx (T-1)(X'X)^{-1}\left((X'X)-\frac{1}{T}X'\iota_T\iota_T'X\right)(X'X)^{-1}\\
=(T-1)^2(X'X)^{-1}\hat{\Sigma}(X'X)^{-1}
$$