# Inverse of $S_{N,N-1}'AS_{N,N-1}$ where $S$ is orthogonal and $A$ is of full rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $S\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N }$ be an orthogonal matrix and denote $S_{N,N-1}\in\mathbb{R}^{N \times N-1}$ as the matrix with the same elements of $S$ but without the last column of $S$.

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$ be of full rank.

I am searching for a representation of the Inverse of $K:=S_{N,N-1}'AS_{N,N-1}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lemma posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/17780/240529:

**Lemma.** If $A$ and $A+B$ are invertible, and $B$ has rank $1$, then let $g=\mathrm{trace}(BA^{-1})$. Then $g\neq -1$ and 
$$(A+B)^{-1} = A^{-1} - \frac{1}{1+g}A^{-1}BA^{-1}.$$

Maybe you can rewrite $S'_{N,N-1}AS_{N,N-1}$ as a sum and use the lemma?

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, even if I'd be able to decompose $A$ into a sum $A=A_1+A_2$ I'd stuck with the same problem as I would be required to compute $(S'A_1S)^{-1}$. On the other hand side I am not aware of a matrix decomposition $S'AS=A+B$.