# Inverse of sum of 3 matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I need a way to compute the inverse of the sum of three matrices:

$(A + BB^T + \beta I)^{-1} $ where $I$ is identity and $\beta$ is a constant.

I am not very familiar with linear algebra, but a quick google search didn't help.

Comment: Are these specific matrices, or just some general matrices?

Comment: If you tell us why you want to find that, we could probably better help.

Comment: I don't think there is any reason to suppose that the inverse exists...

Comment: Let $C=BB^T+\beta I$ (which is symmetric; not sure if that helps). By [this][1] we have that

\begin{align*}
(A+C)^{-1}&= A^{-1}-(I+A^{-1}C)^{-1}A^{-1}CA^{-1}
\end{align*}

as long as $A$ is invertible. Not sure if that helps.
  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices

Comment: I am doing a recursive least squares fit by hand, but i made some alterations to the original derivation, arrived at this step and couldnt continue. 

Let's assume the inverse exist. It should (i think). 

Idk if that helps... I might beable to just make python do this for me without using a closed form. But, i dont think so.

Comment: This question is hard to tackle without any additional information regarding B or A. One thing you can do is to let C = A + bI and use the Woodbury matrix identity, but this won't get you anywhere at least B or A have some structure. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity