# Effective way to calculate the inverse (A+kB)^-1 with k changing and A, B fixed

Tags: matrices, inverse

I have a Simulink modell where I need to calculate $(A+c_k B)^{-1}$ in every time step with $c_k$ changing each iteration. 
Does someone know any more effective way to do it, instead of calculating a completely new inverse in every step? 
Thank you!

Comment: look at: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices. Maybe that it's usefull.

Answer (score 0):

@ Alex B. , specify the considered matrices $A,B$. If $B$ has a small rank, then one can do something for you, otherwise not.

More precisely, if $rank(B)=r$, then, using the Sherman-Morrison formula, we obtain the required inverse with complexity $\sim 3n^2r$ multiplications. That is interesting iff $r<n/3$.