# How to convert $(A+\lambda E)^{-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, matrix-calculus

Here is one of the most famous equation called Sherman–Morrison formula (1951) when we want to get an inverse matrix.

$$(A+vw^{\text{T}})^{-1}=A^{-1}-\cfrac{A^{-1}vw^{\text{T}}A^{-1}}{1+{w}^{\text{T}}A^{-1}v}$$

Then, we consider to get the inverse matrix $(A+\lambda E)^{-1}$ where $E$ is an identical matrix and $\lambda$ is scalar. This is my opinion but I suppose that identical matrix can  be expressed using vector $\bf{e}$ which is defined below.

$$\bf{e}=[\it{e_{\rm{1}}} \it{e_{\rm{2}}} \dots \it{e_{\rm{i}}} \dots \it{e_{\rm{n}}}\rm{]^{\text{T}}}$$

The vector has a characteristic which can be described to multiply another identical vector.

$$
E=\bf{e e^{\text{T}}}=[\it{e_{i}e_{j}}\rm{]} \ \ Then  \ \ \
\rm{
\begin{cases}
1 \ \ (\it{i=j}\rm{)}\\
\\
0 \ \ (i \not= j)
\end{cases}
}
$$

Therefore, $(A-\lambda E)^{-1}$ can be evaluated below using the first formula and my definition.

$$(A+\lambda \bf{e e^{\text{T}}}\rm{)}^{-1}=\it{A}^{\rm{-1}}-\cfrac{\it{A}^{\rm{-1}}\lambda\bf{e e^{\text{T}}}\it{A^{\rm{-1}}}}{\rm{1}+\lambda\bf{e^{\text{T}}}\it{A}^{\rm{-1}}\bf{e}}$$

Thus,
$$\it{A}^{\rm{-1}}\bf{e e^{\text{T}}}\it{A^{\rm{-1}}}=A^{\rm{-2}}$$

$$\displaystyle \bf{e^{\text{T}}}\it{A}^{\rm{-1}}\bf{e}=\sum_{\it{i,j}=\rm{0}}^{\rm{n}}\it{\widetilde{a}_{i,j}e_{i}e_{j}}=\sum_{\it{i}=\rm{0}}^{\rm{n}}\it{\widetilde{a}_{i,i}}=\rm{Tr}(\it{A^{\rm{-1}}}\rm{)}$$

Eventually,

$$(A+\lambda E)^{-1}=A^{-1}-\cfrac{\lambda A^{\rm{-2}}}{1+\lambda\rm{Tr}(\it{A}^{\rm{-1}}\rm{)}}$$

But, this suggestion is totally wrong. In addition the similar question already submitted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices). Although, I don't know why is wrong about my consideration.

Thanks.

Comment: You're using the *matrix* $\mathbf{e}=E$ where the formula requires a *vector*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you mean by
$$
\mathbf{e}=\begin{bmatrix}
e_1 & e_2 & \dots & e_i & \dots & e_n
\end{bmatrix}
$$
If by $e_i$ you mean the $i$-th column of the identity, then you have just rewritten $E$ in a different way and, of course, $\mathbf{e}\mathbf{e}^T=E$, but also
$$
\mathbf{e}^TA^{-1}\mathbf{e}=A^{-1}
$$
and is *not* a scalar, so you can't use it in the denominator of the formula, which assumes the matrix to find the inverse of has the form
$$
A+vw^T
$$
where $v$ and $w$ are column vectors so, in particular, $vw^T$ is a rank $1$ matrix (the case $vw^T=0$ is trivial).

For $n>1$ there are *no* column vectors $v$ and $w$ such that $vw^T=E$, because $E$ has rank $n>1$: you may indeed use the formula in the case $n=1$, which is however so simple that it's not necessary to do any calculation.