# Follow-Up to "Least Squares with Euclidean $(L_2)$ Norm Constaint"

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I would have a couple of follow-up questions to the [following answer made by Royi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399321/least-squares-with-euclidean-l-2-norm-constraint?rq=1#2399848):

The setup is the following:

> $$ \begin{alignat*}{3} \text{minimize} & \quad & \frac{1}{2} \left\| A
> x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} \\ \text{subject to} & \quad & {x}^{T} x \leq 1
> \end{alignat*} $$
>
> The Lagrangian is given by:
>
> $$ L \left( x, \lambda \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b
> \right\|_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} \left( {x}^{T} x - 1 \right) $$
>
> The KKT Conditions are given by:
>
> $$ \begin{align*} \nabla L \left( x, \lambda \right) = {A}^{T} \left(
> A x - b \right) + \lambda x & = 0 && \text{(1) Stationary Point} \\
>  \lambda \left( {x}^{T} x - 1 \right) & = 0 && \text{(2) Slackness} \\
>  {x}^{T} x & \leq 1 && \text{(3) Primal Feasibility} \\ \lambda & \geq
> 0 && \text{(4) Dual Feasibility} \end{align*} $$

1.) Why is the "Slackness" condition fulfilled, i.e. $\lambda\left( x^{T}x - 1 \right) = 0$? After all, we only know that $\left\vert\left\vert x\right\vert\right\vert_{2}^{2} \leq 1$, correct?

2.) Very related: Where do we know from that $\lambda\geq 0$?

3.) Here, the Lagrangian was defined by $\mathcal L \left( x, \lambda \right) := \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} \left( {x}^{T} x - 1 \right)$. One can also define the Lagrangian by $\mathcal L \left( x, \lambda \right) := \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} - \frac{\lambda}{2} \left( {x}^{T} x - 1 \right)$, it shouldn't matter at the end. But in the latter case, would $\lambda\geq 0$ still hold?

4.) I would have a very general question concerning the KKT theorem: Can one also apply them when one deals with equality constraints?

Answer (score 1):

I will try t answer:

1. The slackness condition comes from the condition itself. Either $ \lambda = 0 $ or $ {\boldsymbol{x}}^{T} x = 1 $. Hence the multiplication of them must be zero.
2. This is the definition of Lagrange multiplier for inequality. It basically preserves the direction of the inequality.
3. See above.
4. Yes you cam. Just like you can use KKT for non convex problems. But then some of the properties are lost.

Comment: Do you think you could also take a quick look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4133301/on-the-uniqueness-the-vector-constrained-least-squares-problem)?