# Pseudoinverse of the sum of matrices

Tags: matrices, pseudoinverse

Similarly to the question posted here 
[Inverse of the sum of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices)
but in case of non-square matrices. If I want to compute the pseudoinverse of (A+B) and matrices A,B pinv(A) is known is there a way to compute (or make an approximation) of the new pseudoinverse?? Matrices A and B are full rank.