# Inverse or approximation to the inverse of a sum of block diagonal and diagonal matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

I need to calculate $(A+B)^{-1}$, where $A$ and $B$ are two square, very sparse and very large. $A$ is block diagonal, real symmetric and positive definite, and I have access to $A^{-1}$ (which in this case is also sparse, and block diagonal). $B$ is diagonal and real positive. In my application, I need to calculate the inverse of the sum of these two matrices where the inverse of the non-diagonal one (e.g. $A^{-1}$) is updated frequently, and readily available.

Since $B$ is full rank, the Woodbury lemma is of no use here (well, it is, but it's too slow). Other methods described in [this nice question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices) are of no use in my case as the spectral radius of $A^{-1}B$ is much larger than one. Methods based on a diagonalisation assume that it is the diagonal matrix that is being updated frequently, whereas that's not my case (i.e., diagonalising $A$ is expensive, and I'd have to do that very often).

I'm quite happy to live with an approximate solution.

Answer (score 4):

Let $A_1,A_2,\cdots,A_q$ be the diagonal blocks of $A$, and $a_{1,1},a_{1,2},\cdots,a_{1,n_1},a_{2,1},a_{2,2},\cdots,a_{2,n_2},\cdots,a_{q,1},a_{q,2},\cdots,a_{1,n_q}$ the diagonal elements of $B$, then the inverse of the sum would simply be a diagonal block matrix with blocks: ${(A_i+diag(a_{i,1},\cdots,a_{i,n_i}))}^{-1}$ for $i\in(1,2,\cdots,q)$.

So the problem is reduced to finding the inverse of the sum of a matrix and a diagonal matrix. Fortunately, $A$ is symmetric positive definite, so each $A_i$ diagonalizable, hence, we can write it as follows:

$$
A_i=P_iD_i{P_i}^{T}=P_i\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_{i,1}  & 0     & 0      & \cdots       & 0     & 0 \\
0  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &        & 0 \\\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &   \vdots \\
\vdots   & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
0  &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0      &  \cdots     & 0     & 0      & \lambda_{i,n_{i}}
\end{bmatrix}{P_i}^{T}
$$

Where $\lambda_{i,1},\cdots,\lambda_{i,n_{i}}$ are the eigenvalues of $A_i$, hence:

$$
A_i+diag(a_{i,1},\cdots,a_{i,n_i})=P_i\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_{i,1}+a_{n_i}  & 0     & 0      & \cdots       & 0     & 0 \\
0  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &        & 0 \\\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &   \vdots \\
\vdots   & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
0  &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0      &  \cdots     & 0     & 0      & \lambda_{i,n_{i}}+a_{i,n_i}
\end{bmatrix}{P_i}^{T}
$$

Since $A_i$ and $B$ are symmetric positive definite, then $\lambda_{i,j}+a_{i,j}\neq 0$, so :

$$
{(A_i+diag(a_{i,1},\cdots,a_{i,n_i}))}^{-1}=P_i\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\lambda_{i,1}+a_{i,1}}  & 0     & 0      & \cdots       & 0     & 0 \\
0  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &        & 0 \\\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &   \vdots \\
\vdots   & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
0  &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0      &  \cdots     & 0     & 0      & \frac{1}{\lambda_{i,n_{i}}+a_{i,n_i}}
\end{bmatrix}{P_i}^{T}=P_iD_i{P_i}^{T}
$$

Hence the inverse of ${(A+B)}^{-1}$ is a block diagonal matrix with diagonal elements being the matrices above.

You can rewrite that as

$$
{(A+B)}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
P_1  & 0     & 0      & \cdots       & 0     & 0 \\
0  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &        & 0 \\\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &   \vdots \\
\vdots   & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
0  &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0      &  \cdots     & 0     & 0      & P_q
\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}
D_1  & 0     & 0      & \cdots       & 0     & 0 \\
0  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &        & 0 \\\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &   \vdots \\
\vdots   & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
0  &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0      &  \cdots     & 0     & 0      & D_q
\end{bmatrix}\times\begin{bmatrix}
{P_1}^{T}  & 0     & 0      & \cdots       & 0     & 0 \\
0  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &        & 0 \\\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &   \vdots \\
\vdots   & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
0  &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0      &  \cdots     & 0     & 0      & {P_q}^{T}
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am seriously mistaken, the above answer is incorrect. In my opinion, the problem lies with 
$$
A_i+diag(a_{i,1},\cdots,a_{i,n_i})=P_i\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_{i,1}+a_{n_i}  & 0     & 0      & \cdots       & 0     & 0 \\
0  & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &        & 0 \\\
0 & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots &   \vdots \\
\vdots   & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
0  &        & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0 \\
0 & 0      &  \cdots     & 0     & 0      & \lambda_{i,n_{i}}+a_{i,n_i}
\end{bmatrix}{P_i}^{T}
$$

Let's consider 
$$
P=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\left[\begin{matrix} 2 & -1 \\ 1 & 2\end{matrix}\right]
$$
$$
D=\left[\begin{matrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right] 
$$
$$
B= \left[\begin{matrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Quick calculations show
$$
A + B = PAP^T + B = \left[\begin{matrix} 3.8 & 0.4 \\ 0.4 & 2.2\end{matrix}\right],
$$
but
$$
P ( D + B) P' = \left[\begin{matrix} 3.6 & 0.8 \\ 0.8 & 2.4\end{matrix}\right].
$$

The problem lies in the fact that adding an element to the diagonal of an un-transformed matrix A is not the same as adding it to the diagonal of the diagonalization matrix, i.e.
$$P A P^T + B \neq P (A + B) P^T$$
in general.

Or am I missing something?

PS: Unfortunately, I do not have enough reputation to comment. Sorry for the second answer, please feel free to add this to the original.