# Computation of Matrix inversion

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity

Suppose $\mathbf{A}\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is non-singular and its inverse $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ is known. We would like to compute $\mathbf{B}^{-1}$ where we assume that $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A}+\mathbf{I}$ is also non-singular. Directly computing the inverse of $\mathbf{B}$ requires the order of $O(n^3)$. My question is that is there any way of computing $\mathbf{B}^{-1}$ with reduced complexity, say $O(n^2)$?

Comment: How can you be sure $B$ is non-singular?

Comment: Will the Sherman Morrison formula help? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula

Comment: @user1952500 not a good idea; the matrices both have full rank.  Perhaps the [Woodbury identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) could work, though

Comment: If $\|\mathbf A\|$ is sufficiently small, the inverse can be computed via geometric series, which has linear convergence.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Bernard Suppose $\mathbf{B}$ is also non-singular.

Comment: Check out [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices)