# Yet another bizarre identity involving hypergoemetric functions and gamma functions.

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

Let $d=4$, $T\ge d$ and $p\ge 0$ be integers.

By solving [Spectral densities of finite dimensional sample covariance matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2804671/spectral-densities-of-finite-dimensional-sample-covariance-matrices?noredirect=1&lq=1) we stumbled on a following identity.

\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum\limits_{j=1}^d \left| 
\begin{array}{l}
\left( (\frac{T-d-1}{2}+\delta_{1,j} p+2)^{(\eta-2)} \right)_{\eta=1}^d\\
\left(2^{-\eta} (T-d+1)^{((\delta_{2,j}+\delta_{1,j})p+\eta-1)} \cdot F_{2,1}[\begin{array}{r} 1 & T-d+(\delta_{2,j}+\delta_{1,j})p+\eta \\ & \frac{T-d-1}{2} +\delta_{1,j} p+2\end{array};\frac{1}{2}] \right)_{\eta=1}^d \\
\left( (\frac{T-d-1}{2}+\delta_{3,j} p+2)^{(\eta-2)} \right)_{\eta=1}^d\\
\left(2^{-\eta} (T-d+1)^{((\delta_{4,j}+\delta_{3,j})p+\eta-1)} \cdot F_{2,1}[\begin{array}{r} 1 & T-d+(\delta_{4,j}+\delta_{3,j})p+\eta \\ & \frac{T-d-1}{2} +\delta_{3,j} p+2\end{array};\frac{1}{2}] \right)_{\eta=1}^d
\end{array}
\right|=\\
&&-\frac{p^2}{16} (T-3)^{(p)} \left( T+2 p^2+2 p-3\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Here $a^{(n)} := \prod\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} (a+j)$ is the upper Pochhammer symbol.

We discovered this identity by fixing $p$ and then interpolating a polynomial in $T$ to the left hand side, factoring this polynomial and then recognizing a pattern as a function of $p$.

Now, how would you go about proving this identity in a rigorous manner?

Hint: From the generalized Gauss' second summation theorem we have:
\begin{eqnarray}
F_{2,1}\left[ 
\begin{array}{r}
1 & T+n \\
& \frac{T+m}{2} \\
\end{array}
;\frac{1}{2}
\right] = 
2^{T+n-1} \cdot \left\{
\begin{array}{r}
\Gamma(\frac{T-m}{2} + n+1)\left(\frac{T+m-2}{2}\right) \sum\limits_{l=0}^{m-n-2} \binom{m-n-2}{l} (-1)^{m-n-2-l} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{T+n+l}{2})}{\Gamma(T+n)\Gamma(\frac{4-m+n+l}{2})} & \mbox{if $m \ge n+2$}\\ 
\Gamma(\frac{T+m}{2}) \sum\limits_{l=0}^{n+2-m} \binom{n+2-m}{l} (+1)^{m-n-2-l} \frac{\Gamma(\frac{T+n+l}{2})}{\Gamma(T+n) \Gamma(\frac{m-n+l}{2})} & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{eqnarray}
where $n,m \in {\mathbb Z}$.