# Real parts of diagonal elements of $(I-U)^{-1}(I+U)$ are zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I noticed numerically that real parts of diagonal elements of $(I-U)^{-1}(I+U)$ are zero (assuming $I-U$ is invertible), where $I$ is identity matrix and $U$ is a unitary matrix ($U^\dagger U=I$).

A good example is provided by @copper.hat: take $U={1+i\over \sqrt{2}} I$, then $(I-U)^{-1} (I+U) = (1+\sqrt{2})i I$.

I have tried to use every answer in this question ([Inverse of the sum of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices)) but none of them gives me any hints how to prove this.

By the way, here is a Mathematica script I used to check this using random unitary matrices (adapted here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/creating-a-random-normal-matrix):

```
n = 5; (*any dimension works here*)
q = Orthogonalize[
   RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}] + 
    I RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {n, n}]];
Re[Diagonal[Inverse[IdentityMatrix[n] - q].(IdentityMatrix[n] + q)]]
```

I have to apologize for making too many mistakes at the beginning (even the title was wrong.). I hope some one can help me understand it.

Comment: How do you know the inverse even exists? $I$ is a unitary matrix.

Comment: You are correct. I am referring to a situation when $I-U$ is invertible. Edited accordingly

Comment: $U$ is unitary. Is $UU^* = U^*U$??? What does that say about $U$?

Comment: By definition, $U^{\dagger}U=UU^{\dagger}=I$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix

Comment: I don't get the rush to close here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $U$ is normal it is unitarily diagonalisable. Since it is unitary all eigenvalues lie on the unit circle.

If $U$ is diagonal and $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue on the unit circle then
${1 + \lambda \over 1-\lambda}$ is an eigenvalue of $(I-U)^{-1} (I+U)$. There
is no reason to presume that ${1 + \lambda \over 1-\lambda}$ is real just because
$\lambda$ lies on the unit circle (in fact, it maps the unit circle onto the imaginary line!).

Take $U={1+i\over \sqrt{2}} I$, then $(I-U)^{-1} (I+U) = (1+\sqrt{2})i I$.

**Addendum**: The question has changed, here is an update to the answer.

Let $ U = Q\Lambda Q^* $, where $Q$ is unitary and $\Lambda$ diagonal. Then
$V=(I-U)^{-1} (I+U) = Q(I-\Lambda)^{-1} (I+\Lambda)Q^*$.

Note again that the map $f(z) = {1+z \over 1-z}$ maps the unit circle into the imaginary axis, hence $(I-\Lambda)^{-1} (I+\Lambda)$ purely imaginary and
so $((I-\Lambda)^{-1} (I+\Lambda))^* = - (I-\Lambda)^{-1} (I+\Lambda)$.

It follows from this that $V^* = -V$ and so $V+V^* = 0$. In particular, the
real parts of the diagonal are zero.

Comment: Hi, I am really sorry for making a huge mistake in the title (and body of course). The question is actually real parts of diagonal elements of $(I-U)^{-1}(I+U)$ are zero. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @ChongWang: I added more detail.