# Separation of inverse of invertible addition of matrices

Tags: matrices, inverse

Consider the following $n\times n$ matrix:

$A^T (HQH^T + R)^{-1} A$.

I would like to know if there exists a matrix $M$, such that:
$A^T M A +  A^T R^{-1} A$

If so, what is its definition?

Some background information:

- $A=H\Theta$ is $m\times n$
- $\Theta$ is $n\times n$
- $H$ is $m\times n$ and has full rank
  $n$, as $m>n$.
- $R$ is $m\times m$, diagonal and invertible
- $Q$ is $n\times n$ and positive semidefinite.

These conditions arise, as this term represents the inverse of a covariance matrix, which is composed by different error sources.

Comment: Such that what? Your sentence stops after the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comments, however I just found the desired answer on my own using this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75389
and this paper: http://dspace.library.cornell.edu/bitstream/1813/32750/1/BU-647-M.version2.pdf

Using equation 23 or 24 (for the reduced order of the dimension of the inverse) of the paper, $A^T(HQH^T+R)^{-1}A$ can be shown to be: $A^T R^{-1} A + A^T M A$ (as desired), where:
$M=-R^{-1} H (I + QH^T R^{-1} H)^{-1} Q H^T R^{-1}$

If you are additionally interested in $[A^T(HQH^T+R)^{-1}A]^{-1} = [A^T R^{-1} A + A^T M A]^{-1}$, equation 23/24 can be applied a second time, if you define $P=A^T R^{-1} A$. This has no performance advantages, but allows for interesting comparisons.

No approximations or infinite sums are involved in these expressions and they conform to the given boundary conditions.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, your question boils down to finding $(B+I)^{-1}$. You can use [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series):
$$
(I+B)^{-1}=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-B)^k,
$$
if the series is convergent. You need then to show that a norm of $B=(HQH^TR^{-1})$  is smaller than one and then $M=\sum_{i=1}^\infty (-HQH^TR^{-1})^k$.