# Simplification of $x = \left(A + \sum_i \alpha_i B_i\right)^{-1} A \ y$, $A \succ 0, A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$, $\textrm{rank}(B_i) = 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have a matrix inversion problem on hand. I want to reduce the matrix inversion complexity, if at all feasible. Let me give a brief overview of the problem definition.

**Problem definition**:
Say $A \succ 0, A \in M_{n,n}\left( \mathbb{C} \right)$, is Hermitian and full-rank (positive definite) matrix. $B_i \in M_{n,n}\left( \mathbb{C} \right)$ and **rank-**$1$, $\alpha_i \in  \mathbb{C}$ some constant, $y \in M_{n,1}\left( \mathbb{C} \right)$ some column vector.

\begin{align}
x = \left(A + \sum_{i=0}^m \alpha_i B_i\right)^{-1} A \ y
\end{align}

**Question**: Can this matrix inversion be simplified such that big matrix inversion can be avoided (since $n \approx 8$k)? Thank you in advance.

I can't make any progress with matrix inversion lemmas, e.g., in matrix cookbook.

Comment: does this (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices) help you at all?

Comment: Thanks, I will try that.