# Convexity of a function over matrices

Tags: matrices, functions, convex-optimization

How to show that $f(X)=tr(X^{-1})$ is convex over the set of symmetric real positive definite matrices by showing that $g(t)=f(X+tV)$ is convex for any such $X$ and $V$? Clearly we need to show that $$g(t)\le (1-t)g(0)+tg(1)$$ but I'm stuck to find a simplified version of $tr((X+tV)^{-1})$. 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Also, you might find this question useful too: [Inverse of the sum of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices)

Comment: And [Neumann series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series).