# Reduced complexity of matrix inversion of sum of rank 1 matrices: $M^{-1} = \left( I + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{K} \alpha_i A_i \right)^{-1} $?

Tags: linear-algebra, computational-complexity, numerical-linear-algebra

How to reduce the complexity of matrix inversion of sum of rank 1 matrices, *not only arithmetic but also run time*?

$M^{-1} = \left( I + \sum \limits_{i=1}^{K} \alpha_i A_i \right)^{-1} $

where $A_i \in \mathbb{C}^{N \times N}$, ${\rm rank}\left(A_i \right) = 1$, and  $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{R}$.

For instance, the suggestion [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices/75389) is apprently reducing the arithmetic complexity but not the run time (I mean it will take $N$ iterations to find the matrix inverse)? What other alternatives do we have?