# Inverse of the $(A + iB)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have taken this question from Zhang, Fuzhen. Linear Algebra (Johns Hopkins Studies in the Mathematical Sciences)

> Assuming that all matrix inverses involved below exist, show that
>
> $(A + iB)^{-1} = B^{-1} A(A + AB^{-1} A)^{-1} − i(B + AB^{-1} A)^{-1}.$

I can simplify the right hand side to obtain
$(A + B)^{-1} − i(B + AB^{-1} A)^{-1}$. The hint in the answer key says multiply the right hand side by $(A + iB)$ to verify. But at this point everything is an inverse of the sum. Is there a way to move forward other than using a formula like in this question: [Inverse of the sum of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices)?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a typo. The correct formula should be
$$
(A+iB)^{-1}=(B^{-1}A-iI)(B+AB^{-1}A)^{-1}.
$$
To verify this, multiply the candidate inverse from the left with $A+iB$ to obtain
$$
(A+iB)(B^{-1}A-iI)(B+AB^{-1}A)^{-1}
=(AB^{-1}A-iA+iA+B)(B+AB^{-1}A)^{-1}=I.
$$

Comment: I suspected a typo as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\B{B^{-1}}
\def\C#1{{\mathbb C}^{#1\times #1}}
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1\times #1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\CtoR#1#2{\m{#1 & -#2 \\ \hline #2 & #1}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$It is often useful to convert a $\:\C{n}$ matrix into its $\,\R{2n}$ representation
$$\eqalign{
A+iB \qif \CtoR AB \\
}$$
Now the problem is to find two **real**  matrices $\LR{E,F}$
which satisfy the identity
$$\eqalign{
\m{I&0\\\hline 0&I} = \CtoR AB\bullet\CtoR EF \equiv \m{{AE-BF}&-AF-BE\\\hline {AF+BE}&{AE-BF}} \\
}$$
Solve for the *off-diagonal* component (assuming $\B$ exists)
$$\eqalign{
0 = AF+BE \qiq E = -\B AF \\
}$$
Then the *diagonal* component
$$\eqalign{
BF &= \LR{A\c{E}-I} \;=\; -A\c{\B AF} - I \\
I &= -\LR{B+A\B A}F \\
F &= -\LR{B+A\B A}^{-1} \\
}$$
Go back and eliminate $F$ from the first equation
$$\eqalign{
E
 &= -\B A\c{F} \;=\; \c{+}\B A\c{\LR{B+A\B A}^{-1}} \\
}$$
Therefore
$$\eqalign{
\LR{A+iB}^{-1}
 &=  E \;+\; iF \\
 &=  \B A\LR{B+A\B A}^{-1} \;\;-\;\; i\LR{B+A\B A}^{-1} \\
}$$
So there was definitely a typo in your textbook.