# Inverse of sum of rank one matrices: How to reuse the parts of inverse if there is a change in one of the rank one matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let us suppose $$A := \left( \underbrace{I + \sum_{k=1}^K \alpha_{k} u_ku_k^T}_{:=M} \right)^{-1},$$
>   where $\alpha_k \in \mathbb{R}$, $u_k \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $I$ is an invertible matrix.
>
> We can find the inverse of matrix $M$ using the method proposed by [K. S. Miller](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690437?seq=1) or see example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices?rq=1).

**Question:**

> Now, if $\alpha_k$ has changed/updated, then how to reuse matrix $A$ as efficiently as possible without recomputing the inverse of $M$ from scratch.

The reason I am asking is that there is an iterative algorithm where $\alpha_k$ keeps updating within iterations.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula  when done algorithmically I think people sometimes call it BFGS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that the updated matrix is

$$
B = \left(I + \sum_{k=1}^K \beta_{k} u_ku_k^T \right)^{-1}.
$$
We can compute the updated inverse using the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) if we note that $B = A + UCV$ with $U$ the matrix with columns $u_1,\dots,u_K$, $V = U^T$, and $C = \operatorname{diag}(\beta_1 - \alpha_1, \beta_2 - \alpha_2, \dots, \beta_K - \alpha_K)$.