# How to find the inverse of a linear combination of unitary matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, unitary-matrices

Given scalars $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_\ell \neq 0$ and unitary matrices $U_1, U_2, \dots, U_\ell$, let

$$ A := \sum_{k=1}^{\ell} \alpha_k U_k $$

where the $\ell$ coefficients $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots, \alpha_\ell \neq 0$ are chosen such that matrix $A$ is invertible. Are there theorems that can help one calculate $A^{-1}$?

I know that for the case where $\ell = 2$ there is the nice [Ken Miller (1981)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690437?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) paper, but it isn't obvious to me that I can extend those results to the problem where $\ell > 2$. On Math SE, there is also the nice [Inverse of the sum of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17776), which discusses the $\ell = 2$ problem, but I started a new question because my case is quite a bit different.

Comment: I would describe $A$ not as a *sum* of unitary matrices but as a linear combination of them.

Comment: It may be possible to optimize for small numbers, but do bear in mind that any operator on any Hilbert space is a linear combination of unitaries (see e.g. Kadison and Pedersen, "Means and Convex Combinations of Unitary Operators," which is nowhere near an optimal result of its type)