# Inverse of $A+A^T?$

Tags: matrices, inverse

Let $A = DB$, where $D$ is any diagonal matrix with positive diagonal entries and $B = [b_{ij}]$ is any symmetric
matrix s.t. $B^{\circ -1} = \left[\frac{1}{b_{ij}}\right]$ is positive definite. Can we find the inverse $(A+A^T)^{-1}$ in terms of $B$ and $B^{-1}?$ Here $A^T$ denotes the transpose of $A.$

Any suggestions will be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The inverse may not exists. Do you have any other hypothesis about A that guarantees the existence of the inverse?

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices).

Comment: For example, $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ is invertible, but $A + A^T = 0$ is certainly not. Unless your definition of non-symmetric also prohibits skew-symmetric matrices.

Comment: @hardmath,  i have edited.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think this task is possible? From only the description given, it seems somewhat random to me. Have you tried the case $n=2$, where all inverses can easily be found by hand?