# Inverse of the sum two Kronecker product

Tags: matrices, inverse, pseudoinverse, kronecker-product

We know if we have two matrices  $A$ and $B$ then:

$(A\otimes B )^{-1} = A^{-1} \otimes B^{-1}$

Now if we have four matrices $A,B,C,D$ . Is there an equivalent term for the following?

$((A\otimes B)+ (C\otimes D))^{-1}$

which can reduce the cost computation and memory usage.

Comment: Your problem is effectively the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices). Note that the inverse of the sum need not exist.

Comment: @amir If one of the four matrices has a small rank, then the [Woodbury matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) might be useful.