# Variation on Ricci tensor about metric

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

Picture below is from the "Three manifolds with positive Ricci flow".  I try to calculate the red line.

First, in normal coordinate, I have
$$
E(g_{ij})=-2R_{ij} 
=
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(g^{kl}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}g_{kl})
-
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k}[
g^{kl}(
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}g_{jl}
+
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}g_{il}
-
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^l}g_{ij}
)
]
+(\text{lower order term})
$$
now
$$
DE(g_{ij})\tilde g_{ij} = \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0} E(g_{ij}+s\tilde g_{ij})
$$
I don't know  what is the inverse  of $g_{ij}+s\tilde g_{ij}$. For example, to calculate
$$
 \frac{d}{ds}\Big|_{s=0}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}[(g_{kl}+s\tilde g_{kl})^{-1}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}(g_{kl}+s\tilde g_{kl})]
$$
how should I get the elements of $(g_{kl}+s\tilde g_{kl})^{-1}$ ?  But seemingly, since it is normal coordinate, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}g_{kl}=0$, so there must be
$$
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^i \partial x^j}g_{kl}
$$
therefore, $(g_{kl}+s\tilde g_{kl})^{-1}$ become $g^{kl}$. But why
$$
DE(g_{jk})\tilde g_{jk}=-2\tilde R_{jk}  ~~~?
$$
After all, the lower order terms are omitted. How to see that it is equal to $-2\tilde R_{jk}$ ?  Seemingly, it is a directly calculation!

> [image]

Comment: $g$ and $\bar{g}$ are square matrices. Do you aware of [inverse of sum of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/17776/272127)?

Comment: To calculate $$\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_0(g+s\tilde{g})^{-1},$$ first note that, since $(I+sA)(I-sA) = I - s^2A^2$, it follows that $(I+sA)^{-1} = I - sA + s^2(\cdots)$. Since $g$ is positive definite symmetric, there exists a positive definite symmetric matrix $M$ such that $M^2=g$. Therefore,$$(g+s\tilde{g})^{-1}=(M(I+sM^{-1}\tilde{g}M^{-1})M)^{-1} =M^{-1}(I+sM^{-1}\tilde{g}M^{-1})^{-1}M^{-1}=M^{-1}(I-sM^{-1}\tilde{g}M^{-1})M^{-1}+s^2(\cdots)=g^{-1}-sg^{-1}\tilde{g}g^{-1} + s^2(\cdots)$$ Therefore, $$\left.\frac{d}{ds}\right|_{0}(g+s\tilde{g})^{-1} = -g^{-1}\tilde{g}g^{-1}.$$