# Inverse of $(A+bB )$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I am solving about constrained optimization problem.

To solve this, I have to find conditions that satisfy KKT condition.

From KKT condition, I got matrix equation like $(A+bB)x=C$.

Here, $A$ and $B$ are square symmetric matrix and invertible.
$b$ is scalar value.

I want to solve this theoretically.

Can I express $(A+bB)^{-1}$ with $A, B, b, A^{-1}$, and $B^{-1}$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: It does not exist when $A=B=1, b=-1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices