# Inverse of a linear combination of matrices

Tags: matrices

This is a question that I've been mulling on for a bit. Given some linear
combination of matrices:

\begin{equation*}
 w_{0}A_{0} + w_{1}A_{1} + \ldots + w_{n}A_{n}
\end{equation*}

Assuming that all of these matrices are invertible and known (i.e., each
$A_{i}^{-1}$ is known beforehand for all $i$.), and additionally assuming that
the resulting matrix inverse actually exist (e.g., under floating point
arithmetic), is there some way to efficiently compute the inverse of this
matrix?

Or in other words, can I somehow compute the matrix:

\begin{equation*}
 (w_{0}A_{0} + w_{1}A_{1} + \ldots + w_{n}A_{n})^{-1}
\end{equation*}

Using the matrices $A_{i}^{-1}$? Alternatively, is there a way to
approximate this matrix under the same assumptions?

In my case, these matrices are all 4x4 affine transformation matrices (i.e.,
some combination of a scaling, rotation and translation transform) which may
simplify things in practice, but I'm also curious if this is possible for
general matrices.

I think this is related to this question
[Inverse of the sum of matrices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17776/inverse-of-the-sum-of-matrices),
however, it is not exactly clear to me how this extends to multiple (weighted) matrices, if it actually does so.

Comment: 1) I'm afraid that nothing can be said for more than two matrices. 2) The fact it is *weighted* sum is unimportant because you can incorporate the weights into the matrices.

Comment: I don't see why the linked question doesn't answer your question immediately. You just iterate the formula: $(A_1+A_2+A_3+\dots+A_k)^{-1} = (A+B)^{-1} = C_r^{-1}-g_rC_r^{-1}B_rC_r^{-1}$, where $A=A_1$ and $B=A_2+A_3+\dots+A_k$. In terms of efficiency, however, I do not know.

Comment: Just adding this here since I made an edit: The weights are not known "before-hand", so only the non-weighted matrix inverses would be known to make the computations efficient (if it would be possible)

Comment: @SomeCallMeTim That seems feasible at least, but yeah, probably a bit inefficient. Still, I didn't think of such a simple re-arrangement, I'll see if that could be workable

Comment: @Xaldew Just a small comment: even though the weights are not given before-hand, they are still no problem. $(wA)^{-1} = w^{-1}A^{-1}$ (when the inverse exists).